# linq concat error with two tables

Tags: vb.net, linq, concatenation

I have this two `linq` query:

```
Dim lnqPrüfendeartikel = (From row In dtKonf
                                 Let ARTNR_HZ = row.Field(Of String)("ARTNR-HZ")
                                 Let ENDARTNR = row.Field(Of String)("ARTNR")
                                 Where ARTNR_HZ <> ""
                                 Select ARTNR_HZ, ENDARTNR
                                 Order By ARTNR_HZ).Distinct

Dim lnqPrüfendeartikel2 = (From row In dtKonf
                                 Let ROHNR = row.Field(Of String)("ROHNR")
                                 Let ENDARTNR = row.Field(Of String)("ARTNR")
                                 Where ROHNR <> ""
                                 Select ROHNR, ENDARTNR
                                 Order By ROHNR).Distinct
```

I would like to concat the two result with:

```
lnqPrüfendeartikel.Concat(lnqPrüfendeartikel2)
```

But I get the error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of )' cannot
>   be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of )' because ' (line 177)' is not derived from
>   ' (line 170)', as required for the 'Out' generic
>   parameter 'T' in 'Interface IEnumerable(Of Out T)'

For me, everything seems to be right: I have in both query two fields and the data types are the same too.

What is then the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have selected anonymous types. The property-names are derived from the the name in the `Let`-clause of your LINQ queries. So the first has two properties:

```
ARTNR_HZ As String 
ENDARTNR As String
```

and the second has

```
ROHNR As String 
ENDARTNR As String
```

You can concat only sequences of the same types. But those types are different since their names are different (note that [even the order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154426/284240)). So you could create an anonymous type with the same properties by using the same names and types:

```
Dim lnqPrüfendeartikel = (From row In dtKonf
                         Let ARTNR_HZ = row.Field(Of String)("ARTNR-HZ")
                         Let ENDARTNR = row.Field(Of String)("ARTNR")
                         Where ARTNR_HZ <> ""
                         Select x = New With { Key .HZ = ARTNR_HZ, Key .NR = ENDARTNR }
                         Order By x.HZ).Distinct()

Dim lnqPrüfendeartikel2 = (From row In dtKonf
                         Let ROHNR = row.Field(Of String)("ROHNR")
                         Let ENDARTNR = row.Field(Of String)("ARTNR")
                         Where ROHNR <> ""
                         Select ROHNR, ENDARTNR
                         Select x = New With { Key .HZ = ROHNR, Key .NR = ENDARTNR }
                         Order By x.HZ).Distinct()
```

Now you can concat both:

```
Dim both = lnqPrüfendeartikel.Concat(lnqPrüfendeartikel2)
```

Another apporach is to  change the name of the `Let`-variables to be the same in both queries.